# How to import XOR function from Crypto.Cipher module?

Tags: python, package, cryptography

```
cannot import name 'XOR' from 'Crypto.Cipher' 
(/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py)
```

I just tried importing `XOR` function into my code & this is the error that i have got when i executed my code in the google colab.

Can i get the solution for this?

I just need to import `XOR` function using `Crypto.Cipher` module. My code is as follows

```
import Crypto
from Crypto import Cipher
from Crypto.Cipher import XOR

key = "abcdefghijklij"
xor = XOR.XORCipher(key) # To encrypt
xor1 = XOR.XORCipher(key) # To decrypt

def enc(sock, message, addr):
    abcd = str_xor.encrypt(message)
    print (message == dec(sock, abcd, addr))
    sock.sendto(abcd, addr)
    return abcd

def dec(sock, message, addr):
    abcd = str_xor1.decrypt(message)
    return abcd

#message = "dfjsdfjsdfjdsfdfsk"4
#print message
#newm = enc(1, message, message)
#print newm
#print dec(1, newm, newm)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install crypto
```

installs https://github.com/chrissimpkins/crypto which does not appear to be `import`-able class-library. Its examples and test scripts suggest `crypto` and `decrypto` should be executes as commands.

- Readme:  https://github.com/chrissimpkins/crypto
- Tests/examples: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/crypto/tree/master/tests

Please specify which crypto-library did you install?
Make sure your installation matches the library you are supposed to install.